# Retrieve data (associative array) sent to controller's action with AJAX

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, serialization

I try to POST a form in AJAX and one of the parameter is an associative array. 
I can check in Console that the request is okay and parameters are correctly sent.

This is the AJAX call

```
 var fieldsEdited = [{"Key":1,"Values":["value1"]},{"Key":2,"Values":["value2"]}, ...]
 $.ajax({
    url: "/url"
    type: 'POST',
    data: { fieldsEdited: JSON.stringify(fieldsEdited) },
    dataType: 'json',
    traditional: true,
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) { }
});
```

But I can't "map" these parameters in the action of the controller

I have tried to get them like that

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Method(List<DictionaryInfos> fieldsEdited)
```

with

```
[Serializable]
public class DictionaryInfos
{
    public int Key { get; set; }
    public List<String> Values { get; set; }
}
```

but the result is always an empty array, I can't retrieve correct data.

What is wrong ?

Comment: Try to add [FromBody] attribute before this parameter

Comment: Post your complete ajax call code.

Comment: I have edited my post. Thanks

Comment: @MajkeloDev Adding [FromBody] doesn't change nothing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is at least one problem with your code: `dataType` is not the type of what you're sending to the server, but what you're expecting back from the server.

You must specify `contentType` to let the server know what kind of data you're sending to it:

```
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
```

Besides, it's possible that you need to change

```
data: { fieldsEdited: JSON.stringify(fieldsEdited) },
```

to

```
data: JSON.stringify(fieldsEdited),
```

or even simply to

```
data: fieldsEdited
```